# phpmyadmin import csv file. How to skip error line

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, import-csv

I´m trying to import about 3gb csv files to phpmyadmin. Some of them contains more terminated chars and then importing stops because of wrong fields.

I have two colums which i want to fill. Im using : as terminanting char but when there is more of them in line it just stops. I cannot manage csv files they are too big. I want to skip error lines or look for other solutions. How can i do this ?

csv files looks like this

```
ahoj123:dublin
cat:::dog
pes::lolko
```

Comment: Why can't you fix whatever is creating the file so that all the rows have the correct number of fields?

Comment: *"I cannot manage csv files they are too big."* ... I would either fix the "export" so those extra fields aren't there.  If that is impossible, I would write a script in PHP to remove the extra `:`s from the rows -- Not really *managing* the CSV as you are *manipulating* it programmatically.

Comment: @Barmar these txt files are dumps from leakead databases. I sorted them as best as i could. Some of the lines just are not optimal a was hoping that i can just ignore them and import rest of it

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to import an entire 3GB file through phpMyAdmin; you're likely to hit some resource limit such as execution time or memory usage that will cause PHP to kill the script in the middle of the import. There might be a better way to perform the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to your problem, I have written a simple PHP file that will "fix" your file for you ..

It will open "test.csv" with contents of:

```
ahoj123:dublin
cat:::dog
pes::lolko
```

And convert it to the following and save to "fixed_test.csv"

```
ahoj123:dublin
cat:dog
pes:lolko
```

Bear in mind that I am basing this on your example, so I am letting `$last` keep it's `EOL` character since there is no reason to remove or edit it.
PHP file:

```
<?php

$filename = "test.csv";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r+") or die("Could not open $filename" . PHP_EOL);

$keep = '';
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgets($handle);

    $elements = explode(':', $line);
    $first = $elements[0];
    $key = (count($elements) - 1);
    $last = $elements[$key];

    $keep .= "$first:$last";

}
fclose($handle);


$new_filename = "better_test.csv";
$new_handle = fopen("fixed_test.csv", "w") or die("Could not open $new_filename" . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($new_handle, $keep);
fclose($new_handle);
```